# VBA Excel Single column comparison in 2 worksheets

Tags: vba, comparison

I m new to VBA and I need some assistance to finish my need. I have 2 worksheets. One  worksheet will have integers which will vary according to user input.(column B sheet 1).Another worksheet will have constant integers from 1 to 255 each 256 times.(In column B-Sheet 2-256 1's,256-2's....) (i.e totally 65280 cells).  I need to compare both B Columns in both sheets and write the result in Column D-Sheet 2. If both column values in both sheet match then result column should be equal to column B sheet2. If not, result column should have 0. How can i do this?

Heard cell comparison will consume more time for large inputs. Is there any alternate way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you can loop through all of the rows and compare the cells of each row and write the result.  Here is the code:

```
   Public FirstSheetName As String
Public SecondSheetName As String
Public ResultSheetName As String
Public FirstSheetCol As String
Public SecondSheetCol As String
Public ResultSheetCol As String
Public StartIndex As Long
Public EndIndex As Long
Public Sub CompareTwoCols()
Dim i As Long
Dim ii As Long
FirstSheetName = "Sheet1"
FirstSheetCol = "B"
SecondSheetName = "Sheet2"
SecondSheetCol = "B"
ResultSheetName = "Sheet2"
ResultSheetCol = "D"
StartIndex = 1
EndIndex = 65280
'Initialized result with 0's
For i = StartIndex To EndIndex
If Sheets(SecondSheetName).Range(SecondSheetCol & i).Text <> "" Then
    Sheets(ResultSheetName).Range(ResultSheetCol & i).Formula = 0
End If
Next i
'Loop throuh all first sheet items skip if blank
For ii = StartIndex To EndIndex
If Sheets(FirstSheetName).Range(FirstSheetCol & ii).Text <> "" Then
'Loop through all second sheet items
    For i = StartIndex To EndIndex
    'skip if blank or has a value in it
    If Sheets(SecondSheetName).Range(SecondSheetCol & i).Text <> "" _
    And Sheets(ResultSheetName).Range(ResultSheetCol & i).Text = "0" Then
        If Sheets(FirstSheetName).Range(FirstSheetCol & ii).Value = Sheets(SecondSheetName).Range(SecondSheetCol & i) Then
            ' Match Found
            Sheets(ResultSheetName).Range(ResultSheetCol & i).Formula = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SecondSheetName).Range(SecondSheetCol & i)
        End If
    End If
    Next i
End If
Next ii
End Sub
```

Just set the FirstSheetName,SecondSheetName and ResultSheetName to the applicable sheets.  Then, set the FirstSheetCol, SecondSheetCol and ResultSheetCol. Lastly set the StartIndex to the first Row and the End Index to the LastRow. 
I hope it helps, 
Mike

Comment: @Mike Thanks a lot mike. This works for equal number of integers in both B columns of sheet1 and 2. As i mentioned sheet1 will have variable inputs from user(ranging from 1 to 255). i.e It may contain only 2 values or even 255 values.But all values are distinct. If sheet1 has a '2' in column B the result column D of sheet 2 should have 256 2's which is equalling column B of Sheet 2.  How can i alter the code. Hope my requirement is clear for you

Comment: Update the above script with a nested loop. It should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't realy need to use VBA for that.

You can create a function with : `VLOOKUP`

> Searches for a value in the first column of a table array and returns
>   a value in the same row from another column in the table array.

Exemple:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A1;Sheet2!A1:A15;1;0))=TRUE;0;Sheet1!A1)
```

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx

Comment: Thanks Dekx. This is only my initial requirement.I need VBA to develop my application here after.